# Python: List's first term does not start at 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, simulation

So I'm trying to make a code that simulates free fall its almost all done except that the code starts at '1' instead of '0'. My code is:

```
def simulateFreeFall(mass,deltaT,simulationTime):
    acceleration = 9.81
    velocity = 0
    length = 0
    velocity1 = 0
    length1 = 0
    times = []
    l = []
    v = []
    a = []
    x = 0
    timeStep = simulationTime / deltaT
    while x < timeStep:
        elapsedTime = deltaT * x 
        Dvelocity = acceleration * deltaT
        velocity1 = Dvelocity + velocity
        velocity = velocity1
        v.append(velocity1)
        a.append(acceleration)
        Dlength = velocity1 * deltaT
        length1 = Dlength + length
        length = length1
        l.append(length1)
        times.append(elapsedTime)
        x += 1
    plt.plot(times, l, 'rs')
    plt.title("Free Fall - No Friction")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Fall Length")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    print(l[0])

simulateFreeFall(70,0.01,60)
```

When I run the code the first length in the list " l " is 0.000981 instead of 0 I'm not sure what I did wrong for it to start at technically what is supposed to be after 0.01 seconds.

Comment: It's clear from your code that x is starting at 0, so the title of your problem seems inaccurate.  Could you get your question title to match the question you're asking?  Maybe something like "Why is this loop's first term not 0?"  That's not ideal, but it's better.  Also, this doesn't solve your problem, but why are you converting length1 and elapsedTime to floats?  Aren't they already floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some prints to debug this. By using `print` along the flow you can see what is happening.

Nothing surprising is happening, `l[0]` is:

```
l[0] = length1 = Dlength + length = velocity1 * deltaT + lenght = 
= (Dvelocity + velocity ) * deltaT + lenght
```

and the key thing is that

```
Dvelocity = acceleration * deltaT
```

which are non-zero

Comment: Not quite sure how to fix it while keeping all the future calculations the same, would rearranging where the equations are in the function fix it?

Comment: the issue is that your velocity calculation is wrong. `velocity = acceleration * elapsed_time` which is 0 for the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

velocity1 is not 0 in the first loop, so length1 is not 0

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is you calculate the velocity out of the acceleration and your time step which is not 0 in the first step and therefore the first length is neither

Comment: If I rearranged it so that the velocity formula is after the length formula would that fix it?